# Why doesn't my number sequence print from the 2d arraylist correctly?

Tags: arraylist, printing, 2d, indexoutofboundsexception, distinct-values

I cannot get the loop to work in the buildDimArray method to store the number combinations "11+11", "11+12", "11+21", "11+22", "12+11", "12+12", "12+21", "12+22", "21+11", "21+12", "21+21", "21+22", "22+11", "22+12", "22+21", and "22+22" into the 2d arraylist with each expression going into one column of the index dimBase-1 row.  The loop may work for other people, but for some reason mine isn't functioning correctly.  The JVM sees the if dimBase==1 condition, but refuses to check the other conditions.  The "WTF" not being printed as a result from the buildDimArray method.  If dimBase=1, it prints successfully, but doesn't for the other integers.  The dimBase==3 condition needs a loop eventually. The "WTF" is for illustrative purposes.  I could get away with a 1d arraylist, but in the future I will likely need the 2d arraylist once the program is completed.

```
package jordanNumberApp;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/*
 * Dev Wills
 * Purpose: This code contains some methods that aren't developed.  This program is supposed to    
 *  store all possible number combinations from numbers 1-dimBase for the math expression
 *  "##+##" into a 2d arraylist at index row dimBase-1 and the columns storing the 
 *  individual combinations.  After storing the values in the arraylist, the print method 
 *  pours the contents in order from the arraylist as string values. 
 */

public class JordanNumberSystem {


    // a-d are digits, assembled as a math expression, stored in outcomeOutput, outcomeAnswer    
    public static int dimBase, outcomeAnswer, a, b, c, d; 
    public static String inputOutcome, outcomeOutput;
    public static final int NUM_OF_DIMENSIONS = 9; //Eventually # combinations go up to 9 
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dimBaseArray;
    public static Scanner keyboard;

    /*
     * Constructor for JordanNumber System
     * accepts no parameters
     */
    public JordanNumberSystem() // Defunct constructor
    {


// Declare and Initialize public variables
        this.dimBase = dimBase;
        this.outcomeOutput = outcomeOutput;
        this.outcomeAnswer = outcomeAnswer;


    }

    // Set all values of variable values
    public static void setAllValues()
    {
        // Initialize
        dimBase = 1; 
        outcomeAnswer = 22;  // variables not used for now
        outcomeOutput = "1"; // variables not used for now
        //a = 1; 
        //b = 1;
        //c = 1; 
        //d = 1;
        dimBaseArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    }


    public static void  buildDimArray(int dim)
    {
        dimBase = dim;  

        try 
        {

           //create first row 

           dimBaseArray.add(dimBase-1, new ArrayList<String>());


           if( dimBase == 1)
           {

               a = b = c = d = dimBase ; 
               dimBaseArray.get(0).add(a+""+b+"+"+c+""+d);
               System.out.println("WTF");       // SHOWS
           }


           else if (dimBase == 2)
           {  // dim = 2
               a = b = c = d = 1 ;
               System.out.println("WTF");       // doesn't show
          //     dimBaseArray.get(dimBase-1).add(a+""+b+"+"+c+""+d);

                   for( int i = 1 ; i <= dim ; i++)
                       a=i;

                       for( int j = 1 ; j <= dim ; j++) 
                           b=j;

                           for( int k = 1 ; k <= dim ; k++) 
                               c=k;

                               for( int l = 1 ; l <= dim ; l++) 
                               {
                                   d=l;

                                  dimBaseArray.get(dim-1).add(a+""+b+"+"+c+""+d);

                               }

           }
           else if (dimBase == 3)
           {
               a = b = c = d = dimBase;
               dimBaseArray.get(2).add(a+""+b+"+"+c+""+d);
               System.out.println("WTF");
           }



        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
        {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 

    }

    public static void printArray(int num) // Prints the contents of the array
    { // Fixing the printing method
        try 
        {
           int i = num-1; 

           for( String string : dimBaseArray.get(i)) 
           {
              System.out.println(string);
              System.out.println("");
           }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
        {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }                   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

        setAllValues(); // sets the initial a,b,c,d values and dimBase, initializes 2d arraylist
        // Get the Dimension Base number
        System.out.println("Enter Dimension Base Number.  Input an integer: ");
        int dimBaseInput = keyboard.nextInt();    // Receives integer

        dimBase = dimBaseInput;
                if( dimBase != 1  && dimBase != 2 && dimBase != 3)
                {// Error checking
                    System.out.println("invalid Dimension Base Number should be 1 or 2 ");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
     // Build the arraylist, print, clear, exit
                    buildDimArray(dimBase);
                    printArray(dimBase);
                    dimBaseArray.clear();
                    System.exit(1);


    }

}// End of class
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yet?

Comment: I have tried it.  It wasn't very helpful.  Perhaps I could try a better debugger.  Not sure what useful tools are out now.  I would like to know if someone else could make this code work.  Perhaps there is a mistake I overlooked, or the environment could be faulty.